# SSIS 2008 - ForEach Loop to look at specific group/list of files

Tags: csv, ssis, grouping, foreach-loop-container

Ive been searching the internet to what I thought would be a straight forward question to answer.  Hope you guys can help?

I am using for each loop to look for specific files and move them with file system task to a different folder.

Say I have 10 csv files. called listed A to J

I only want to move a,e and j  but cant seem to get the foreachloop to look for that group.

In the enumerator Files text box i have tried inserting the 3 file names split by various separators, but SSIS thinks its all one specific file and none of the 3 get moved.

Can someone advise how it can be done?  Just to confirm, I dont to use wild card logic just group of specific file names - similur to the IN function of SQL query

Thanks in advance

[now added img - please advise how to slect 3 specific files in the text box with arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8zVb.jpg)

Comment: It is better to actually show the code you have tried rather than describing it.

Comment: Put the file names you want to loop through into an SSIS object. Then use a ForEach container to move only those files.

Comment: NoChinDeluxe - i have now added image to request  - showing the text box where i am trying mulitple versions of selecting a group of files

Comment: FreakyHat - please can you advise which SSIS object?  All i want he foreachloop to do is run through a specific list of files instead of a wildcard approach.  Is there no way within the text field to specify the 3 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since OP isn't able to proceed with just my comment, I'll explain a bit more in detail -

1. Use an `EXECUTE SQL TASK` to dump the names of the files needed into an SSIS object (to do this you could use a stored procedure or an SQL query). Create an object-type variable in the variables tab prior, change the output in the `EXECUTE SQL TASK` to `Full Result Set` and map the result to the object you just created. Now this object holds the list of files you need to loop through.
2. Now drag-and-drop a ForEach container from the SSIS toolbox. It should be configured as a `ForEach ADO Enumerator` and map the object to it. Create another variable of type string that will hold the file names after each iteration of the ForEach container. Map this also in the `Variables` tab of the ForEach container.
3. Now, place the `File System Task` which you would use to move these files into the ForEach loop. Use the file-name-variable you created to move just the required files.

Now if you're not sure what SQL query to use for your case in step 1 to get the 3 file names -

```
SELECT 'A.csv'
UNION
SELECT 'E.csv'
UNION 
SELECT 'J.csv'
```

Comment: So, just to confirm. Using the text box (see img on OP) of the ForEachLoop where I would normally use *.csv. I can't simply list the 3 files there?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. I've seen only wildcards used in the text box you mention. Whatever you input there would be taken as the file name, so without a wildcard it would just be one file and the whole point of a `ForEach` container is lost.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried your steps but get error on the execute SQL task object.  Created object variable called it object. Created execute sql task put to full result set.  Will send screenshot of error, when I get back home.  Can you provide screenshot of execute sql task, toto make sure I have done everything correctly?

Comment: All that seems to be quite right, I have nothing else to add. Details of the error?

Comment: [Execute SQL Task] Error: The result binding name must be set to zero for full result set and XML results.

Comment: Execute SQL Task -> Result Set  -> Set Result Name to '0' (without the quotes)

Comment: Sorry still doesnt work - i now get an error on file system task "Variable Object is not a string"  i set source variable = Object and destination variable = filelocation as string

Comment: unfortunately I cank add any more pics/links due to my profile score

Comment: Look at step 2 again. You need to create a string variable and use that in the `ForEach` container configuration to get the values for each iteration. Use this string variable in the `File System Task`

Comment: I now tried calling the result name 0 and variable = User::Object.  I get a bit further but get another error [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "select 'A.csv' union 'E.csv'" failed with the following error: "Incorrect syntax near 'E1.csv'.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Comment: I got it working, I just needed to add the folder location in my union query and all works.  Sorry being hard work, but got there in the end!